# How can I find the robot soccer field feature's like L and T?

Tags: opencv, shapes, pattern-recognition

I want to find the humanoid RoboCup soccer field features like corner lines that have a shape like"L" and the corners of field's center line, that have shape like"T".
Which method and algorithm is good for thit? Is there any article's about it?

Comment: can you supply 1 or 2 example images? a trivial approach would be line and corner detection; maybe with an addition of a classifier; but its hard to answer with such information.

Comment: I don't know of any algorithms that explicitly look for those elements in an image. Corner detectors might return those points among many points so they might not be feasible. I think one of the best way to handle this is to first detect lines using an algorithm like Hough Transform (implemented in OpenCV as HoughLines) and then look for points of intersection of lines. If 2 lines intersect "near" their ends, then it is likely to be a "L" shaped corner. The "T" case should be similar. Of course I'm assuming here that these lines are not partially occluded, which would make things harder.